# Simplifying $e^{2x+1/2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So I was taking some derivatives and the question was

> $e^{2x+\frac{1}{2}}$
>   convert this to $a\cdot b^x$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

This is apparently needed to take the derivative of it without using the chain rule.

Any idea how to tackle this? Tried to manipulate it but I always end up with both of the constants having powers.

Answer (score 5):

Since $e^{a+b} = e^ae^b$ and $e^{ab} = (e^a)^b$ you have$$e^{2x+\frac{1}{2}}=(e^2)^x\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
Thus $b=e^2$ and $a=\sqrt{e}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$$
$$e^{ab}=(e^a)^b$$

Comment: That I know, still can’t find a good answer.

Comment: @user549904 If you use the first property then, can you write $e^{2x+1/2}$ as $e^? e^?$?

Comment: I think we are supposed to have a constant and another constant to some power.

Comment: @user549904, remember that at the end of the day, $e$ is just a number, so raising it to a numerical power results in a constant.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{2x+\frac12}=e^{2x}\cdot e^{\frac12}=\sqrt e\cdot(e^2)^x$$So $a=\sqrt e, b=e^2$

Comment: It is $e^{2x + 1/2}$ not $e^{(2x+1)/2}$. I didn't downvote btw.

Comment: Could be either, the question doesn't make it clear (I would have written it $2x+\frac12$ were it what you believe. Let the OP correct me if needed.

Comment: Mattos is right here actually, I don’t understand why you just divided it by two?

Comment: How you formatted the $\frac 12$ made it confusing.

Comment: Fixed now to reflect the clarification.